# How to programmatically replace ScriptManager with ToolkitScriptManager on MasterPage

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am working with a legacy web app that uses MasterPages that contain a ScriptManager. I need to add content pages that utilize thhe ToolScriptManager thus, I have attempted to programmatically find and replace the old control with the new version. When I step through the code, after I remove the ScriptManager, it still exists, even after a post back. I have tried a number of different ways but I outline the general idea below. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

MasterPage.master contains:

```
<asp:scriptmanager id="ScriptManagerOld" runat="server"></asp:scriptmanager>
```

MasterPage.master.cs contains:

```
public ScriptManager MasterScriptManager
{
    get{return ScriptManagerOld;}
}
```

ContentPage.aspx.cs contains:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReplaceScriptManager();
}

private void ReplaceScriptManager()
{
    try
    {
        Page page = this.Page;

        //remove any instances of non-toolkit script manager
        // attempt 1
        if (Master.MasterScriptManager != null)
        {
            ScriptManager smngr = Master.MasterScriptManager;
            page.Controls.Remove(smngr);
            smngr.Dispose();
        }
        // attempt 2
        if (Master.MasterScriptManager != null)
        {
            ScriptManager smngr = Master.MasterScriptManager;
            page.Controls.Remove(smngr);
            page.Controls.Remove(smngr.Parent);
            smngr.Dispose();
        }
        // attempt 3
        if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(page) != null)
        {
            ScriptManager smngr = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(page);
            page.Controls.Remove(smngr);
            smngr.Dispose();
        }
        // Add new ctrl
        ToolkitScriptManager scriptMngr = new ToolkitScriptManager();
        scriptMngr.ID = "ToolkitScriptManager";
        scriptMngr.EnablePageMethods = true;
        scriptMngr.CombineScripts = false;
        // Exception on next line... cannot add two instances of scriptmanager
        page.Page.Form.Controls.Add(scriptMngr);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw (ex);
    }
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReplaceScriptManager();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing this tag:

```
<asp:scriptmanager id="ScriptManagerOld" runat="server"></asp:scriptmanager>
```

with

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager id="ScriptManagerOld" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager >
```

In your master page it should enough ToolKit manager is backward compatible.

If you want to modify controls in MOSS you need to do it in the "PreInit" event.

This is how you add the ScriptManager **OnPreInit**

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this);
        if (scriptManager == null)
        {
            scriptManager = new ScriptManager();
            this.Page.Form.Controls.AddAt(0, scriptManager);
        }


        base.OnPreInit(e);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Dalorzo. That would definitely work... prblem is I need to do it programmatically because during deplyment, somehow the old style ScripManager is being injected (a MOSS 2007 application) and I can't figure out how to prevent this so we are trying to do it programmatically.